# How to move the linked list from the last list to the front list in C?

Tags: c, linked-list

Basically this is all my coding for the project:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

void newThesis();
void listThesis();
void moveThesis();

struct thesis
{
    int thesis;
    char stud_name[30];
    char stud_id[10];
    char thesis_title[40];
    int thesis_year;
    struct thesis *ptrnext;
};

struct thesis *headptr, *newptr, *currentptr, *previousptr;

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int choice=TRUE;
    headptr=(struct thesis *)NULL;
    while(choice==TRUE)
    {
        printf("\n\nE - Enter thesis information");
        printf("\nL - List all thesis");
        printf("\nM - Move last node to first node");
        printf("\nX - Exit\n");
        printf("\nEnter choice: ");
        scanf(" %c",&ch);
        switch(ch)
    {
        case 'E':newThesis();break;
        case 'L':listThesis();break;
        case 'M':moveThesis();break;
        case 'X':choice=FALSE; break;
        default: printf("\nEnter only one from the above");
    }
}
return 0;
}

void newThesis()
{
    newptr=(struct thesis *)malloc(sizeof (struct thesis));
    if (headptr== NULL)
    {
        headptr=newptr;
        newptr->ptrnext= NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        newptr->ptrnext=headptr;
        headptr=newptr;
    }
    printf("\nTHESIS CODE:");
    printf("\n1 - Online Information Management System");
    printf("\n2 - Cursor Movement Using Finger Gesture");
    printf("\n3 - Tomato Maturity Estimator ");

    printf("\n\nEnter thesis code: ");
    scanf("%d",&newptr->thesis);
    printf("\nEnter student name: ");
    scanf("%s",&newptr->stud_name);
    printf("\nEnter student id: ");
    scanf("%s",&newptr->stud_id);
    printf("\nEnter thesis title: ");
    scanf("%s",&newptr->thesis_title);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter thesis year: ");
    scanf("%d",&newptr->thesis_year);
    fflush(stdin);

    listThesis();
}

void listThesis()
{
    if (headptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nEmpty list");
        return;
    }
    currentptr=headptr;
    do
    {
        printf("\n\n%d",currentptr->thesis);
        printf("\n%s",currentptr->stud_name);
        printf("\n%s",currentptr->stud_id);
        printf("\n%s",currentptr->thesis_title);
        printf("\n%d",currentptr->thesis_year);
        printf("\n");
        currentptr=currentptr->ptrnext;
    }
    while(currentptr != NULL);
}
```

I'm having a problem on how to move the last list that have been inserted to the front list.

I've tried many solutions from the internet and it didn't work. And the new function for it should be

```
void moveThesis();
```

*EDITED: I've got the answer and it works just great!!

```
void moveThesis()
{
    currentptr = headptr;
    do
    {
    previousptr=currentptr;
    currentptr=currentptr->ptrnext;
    }while(currentptr->ptrnext !=NULL);

    currentptr->ptrnext=headptr;
    headptr=currentptr;
    previousptr->ptrnext=NULL;

    listThesis();
}
```

Thanks for helping me guys!

Comment: This is C#? Looks like C

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is a simplified version but the code should work the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct thesis
{
    int data;
    struct thesis *ptrnext;
};

struct thesis *headptr=NULL, *newptr, *currentptr, *previousptr;

void printList() {
    currentptr = headptr;
    while(currentptr!=NULL) {
        printf("%d, ", currentptr->data);
        currentptr = currentptr->ptrnext;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void newThesis(int number)
{
    newptr=(struct thesis *)malloc(sizeof (struct thesis));
    newptr->data = number;
    if (headptr== NULL)
    {
        headptr=newptr;
        newptr->ptrnext= NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        newptr->ptrnext=headptr;
        headptr=newptr;
    }
}

void moveThesis() {
    currentptr = headptr;
    if(currentptr == NULL || currentptr->ptrnext==NULL)
        return;
    while(currentptr->ptrnext != NULL) {
        previousptr = currentptr;
        currentptr = currentptr->ptrnext;
    }

    struct thesis *lastNode = currentptr;
    previousptr->ptrnext = NULL;
    lastNode->ptrnext = headptr;
    headptr = lastNode;
}

int main()
{
    newThesis(2);
    newThesis(5);
    newThesis(-3);
    newThesis(1);
    printList();
    moveThesis();
    printList();
}
```

Comment: I just tested the code and it works perfectly. It must be something else that caused the problem.

Comment: one question, what is the purpose of `int main()
{
    newThesis(2);
    newThesis(5);
    newThesis(-3);
    newThesis(1);
    printList();
    moveThesis();
    printList();
}`  can you explain it a bit?

Comment: It's just a test to push nodes to the head of the linked list in the function `newThesis()`. So in this test, after all four pushes the list is `{1,-3,5,2}`. After you call `moveThesis()` function, the last one will be moved to the head of the list. Thus you will see the list becomes `{2,1,-3,5}`.

Answer (score 0):

Each time u create a struct space to insert ur data its called node not list.

try this code for moving the last node to first node.

```
      void moveThesis()
      {
        currentptr = headptr;
        if(currentptr == NULL || currentptr->ptr == NULL)
              return;
        while(currentptr->ptrnext->ptrnext != NULL)
              currentptr = currentptr->ptrnext;
        currentptr->ptrnext->ptrnext = headptr;
        headptr = curerntptr->ptrnext;
        curerntptr->ptrnext = NULL;
      }
```

and try to return a variable to get the status of the operation done.